# Add-on cannot be installed without Atlassian Connect

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, ondemand

I'm trying to develop a plug-in voor JIRA OnDemand.
I've installed the Atlassian SDK and was able to create some issues and projects etc.

When I tried to upload my plugin descriptor ("atlassian-connect.json"), JIRA tells me the plug-in cannot be installed. It seems Atlassion Connect is not properly installed.

The Log output is below.

Any tips?

```
com.atlassian.upm.spi.PluginInstallException: This add-on cannot be installed without the Atlassian Connect framework. See our <a href="https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/IYHLEg" target="_blank">documentation</a> for more information.
    at com.atlassian.upm.core.install.DefaultPluginInstallationService.execute(DefaultPluginInstallationService.java:118)
    at com.atlassian.upm.core.install.DefaultPluginInstallationService.install(DefaultPluginInstallationService.java:84)
    at com.atlassian.upm.install.UpmPluginInstallationService.install(UpmPluginInstallationService.java:93)
    at com.atlassian.upm.core.rest.resources.install.InstallTask.installFromFile(InstallTask.java:123)
    at com.atlassian.upm.core.rest.resources.install.InstallFromUriTask.executeTask(InstallFromUriTask.java:87)
    at com.atlassian.upm.core.rest.resources.install.InstallTask.call(InstallTask.java:58)
    at com.atlassian.upm.core.rest.resources.install.InstallTask.call(InstallTask.java:33)
    at com.atlassian.upm.core.rest.async.AsynchronousTaskManager$1.call(AsynchronousTaskManager.java:77)
    at com.atlassian.upm.core.rest.async.AsynchronousTaskManager$1.call(AsynchronousTaskManager.java:72)
    at com.atlassian.sal.core.executor.ThreadLocalDelegateCallable.call(ThreadLocalDelegateCallable.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

My descriptor:

```
{
    "authentication": {
        "type": "jwt"
    },
    "baseURL": "https://localhost/",
    "key": "eu.take-a-byte.synctool",
    "apiVersion": "1",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Tool to syncronize JIRA activity with Toggl",
    "name": "JIRA/Toggl Sync Tool", 
    "modules": 
    {
        "webPanels": [
            {
                "url": "/ui",
                "weight": 100,
                "location": "atl.jira.view.issue.right.context",
                "key": "toggl-component",
                "name": {
                    "value": "Toggl"
                }
            }
        ],
        "webhooks": [{
                "event": "jira:issue_created",
                "url": "/issue-created"
            },
            {
                "event": "jira:issue_updated",
                "url": "/issue-updated"
            }
        ]
    },
    "vendor": {
        "name": "Take A Byte",
        "url": "http://www.take-a-byte.eu"
    },
    "lifecycle": {
        "installed": "/installed",
        "uninstalled": "/uninstalled",
        "enabled": "/enabled",
        "disabled": "/disabled"
    }
}
```

Atlassian SDK version:

```
ATLAS Version:    5.0.3
ATLAS Home:       C:\Users\Rick_2\atlassian-plugin-sdk
ATLAS Scripts:    C:\Users\Rick_2\atlassian-plugin-sdk\bin
ATLAS Maven Home: C:\Users\Rick_2\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven-3.2.1
--------
Executing: "C:\Users\Rick_2\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin\mvn.bat" --version -gs C:\Users\Rick_2\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven-3.2.1/conf/settings.xml
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T18:37:52+01:00)
Maven home: C:\Users\Rick_2\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre
Default locale: nl_NL, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Correct advice

The advice below was valid at the time but is no longer. These days you should be using your own personal [Cloud Development Environment](http://answers.atlassian.com/).

### Obsolete advice

You seem to be missing the Atlassian Connect framework from your local JIRA instance. Did you run JIRA locally as the [Atlassian Connect Getting Started page](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/guides/getting-started.html) recommends?

> atlas-run-standalone --product jira --version 6.4-OD-16-006 --bundled-plugins com.atlassian.bundles:json-schema-validator-atlassian-bundle:1.0.4,com.atlassian.webhooks:atlassian-webhooks-plugin:2.0.0,com.atlassian.jwt:jwt-plugin:1.2.2,com.atlassian.upm:atlassian-universal-plugin-manager-plugin:2.19-D20150321T001323,com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-connect-plugin:1.1.26 --jvmargs -Datlassian.upm.on.demand=true

After you do that then try and install your addon again. Cheers!

P.S. [Atlassian Answers](http://answers.atlassian.com/) is probably the best place to ask questions like this.